# Styling links with external style sheets

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm trying to style one link on my page, which has the class=b2t

I want it to remain white at all times except when users mouse over it, in which case I want it to turn green.

I simply cannot figure out how to apply the **hover** and **color** properties to that one link within the class=b2t.

Can anyone advise me on this please?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="b2t">
        <a class="b2t" href="#">
            <img src="images/backtotop.png">
            Back to top
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
a.b2t {
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You write `mdn hover` to google, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover BTW, what's wrong with `a.b2t:hover { color: magic-pink; }`?

Comment: Try this:  [http://liveweave.com/tCa9uE](http://liveweave.com/tCa9uE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PndxC/)

Try this:

```
a.b2t:link, a.b2t:visited, a.b2t:active {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.b2t:hover {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent!

I trawled the net for info which would explain how to tag properties onto the classes of elements like this, but came up with nothing. Is there somewhere I can read up on this?

Comment: These are called **pseudo-classes**, and you can [**read more about them here!**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this.

http://liveweave.com/tCa9uE

Just add:

```
a.b2t:hover { color: Green; }
```